# Host to Guest SSH issue

Tags: ssh, openssh, linux-headers

I want to access the guest linux configured in virtual box using ssh, but it is not permit. I can connect guest os to host os using ssh but reverse is not possible

Comment: Not enough information for us to debug. Ssh server running? Firewall? Networking? Error messages?

Comment: He needs a bridged network adapter.  He's using nat.  That's the problem.

Comment: Yaa, everything is checked, looks ok. And also set network adapter, still not working.